# Trying to decipher the hole or shaft sizes in a stepper motor diagram

Tags: stepper-motor, diagram

Trying to decipher the hole or shaft sizes in a stepper motor diagram.

I am using this stepper motor as an example, but the question applies to a notation in all similar types of diagrams:
https://components101.com/motors/28byj-48-stepper-motor

[image]

I am confused about how sizes (red question marks) are specified in the below diagram:

[image]

How do I read the radius or diameter of the hole shown above or the diameter of the stepper motor shaft from the above diagram?

A link to an online article explain how to read this type of sizing diagrams woyld be a great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimensions give the hole diameter, and the outer radius of the tabs.

The position of the arrows indicate where things are being measured from. In the case of the radius and diameter measurements, these are from the hole centres as indicated by the lines extended beyond the arrow heads into the centre of the hole.

---

Lets start with the hole diameters

```
2 - ɸ4.2±0.15
```

Broken down this gives:

```
2     - The dimension applies to two holes in the diagram - both tabs in this case
ɸ4.2  - The hole diameter is 4.2 units (probably millimeters)
±0.15 - The holes have a tolerance of plus or minus 0.15 units
```

---

The tabs are then described in terms of an outer radius to give you an idea of the size of the tab and how much material there is, and in this case by extension, how big of a screw head or washer can be.

```
2 - R3.5
```

Again broken down:

```
2    - Again the dimension applies to two holes, both tabs.
R3.5 - The tabs have a nominal outer radius of 3.5 units
```

---

The measurements hint at the holes being designed for M4 clearance as noted by @Brian in the comments.

However if planning to use an M4 bolt, the maximum head diameter of 7mm indicated by the tab sizes would require use of either a small-head hex bolt, or at a push a pan head bolt. A standard M4 bolt head diameter may well be too large.

Comment: Note that 4.2-0.15 mm gives comfortable clearance for M4 mounting bolts. hinting at an appropriate mounting method.

Comment: Thank you for help. What is the name of this notation? What keywords do I need to search on google to learn more bout this? Did you learn this in college? what was the course or subject name?

Comment: "Technical Drawing" when I was at high school. Mechanical CAD, probably, now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

### \$\color{red}{\text{RED BOX}}\$

2 holes of diameter (\$\phi\$) 4.2 mm with a tolerance of +/- 0.15 mm

### \$\color{purple}{\text{PURPLE BOX}}\$

2 lugs of radius 3.5 mm

Comment: I don't think the purple box (which you labelled as "red") is indicating holes; it's talking about the outer radius of that tab.

Comment: @Hearth - corrected.

Comment: You've still called the purple box "red" in your description.

Comment: Hehe oops a daisy!